# Write a regular expression in order to search a substring C#

Tags: c#, regex, string, substring

I have a string which I want to examine and search for a substring within it. If the substring is found, I want to do something on the original string.

The string looks like this:

```
"\r\radmin@Modem -- *<456> \radmin@Modem -- *<456> "
```

**Goal:** Search the substring pattern **" -- *<456> "** if it exists in the string, and return success or fail (the digits number is between 1 to infinite: 1, 5, 36, 76, 478, 975 etc.).

What is the regular expression pattern which I need?

Comment: what about `@"-- \*<\d+>"` ?

Comment: yes, its OK and works, Thank you!

Comment: Don't consider me as a hater, but this clearly is question "write a code for me" - it still gets upvotes and tons of responses, and even no comment "what have you tried?". It's kinda wrong, don't you think?

Comment: @insomnium_ It's not wrong, and my tries was not relevant because nothing works for me (I'm still new with Regex), so I asked for help how to write the Regex that I needed to, and I don't see any problem with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
var myRegex = new Regex("(?<=<)[0-9]+(?=>)");
string resultString = myRegex.Match(yourString).Value;
Console.WriteLine(resultString);
// matches 456
```

See the match in **[the Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/gM4pI1/5)**.

**Explanation**

- The lookbehind `(?<=<)` asserts that what precedes is `<`
- `[0-9]+` matches one or more digits
- The lookahead `(?=>)` asserts that what follows is `>`

Comment: This is works fine, and its quite simple I need to admit :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this following piece of code to check if your pattern exist :

```
 string yourInput = "\r\radmin@Modem -- *<456> \radmin@Modem -- *<456> "  ; 
 string pattern = @"<(\d+)>"; 
 boolean success = Regex.Match(yourInput , pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success ;
```

`success` will be true if a number is found.

Comment: Thank you, I will check that.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this regex

```
<[1-9][0-9]*>
```

**explanation**:

```
[1-9]
```

this part is a range from 1-9 so your number is bigger than 0

```
[0-9]*
```

number range from 0-9 and the * gives you the possibility to have number as big as you want

**other way:**
you can also use special characters for numbers, but then it really depends on the regex syntax

```
\d
```

Answer (score 1):

With this pattern you can match the string: `"--\s\*\<\d{3}\>"` 
Note: If the number of digits can change, use this: `"--\s\*\<\d{MIN,MAX}\>"` where `MIN` and `MAX` are the number of digits that can appear in your string (within the part we are interested in matching).

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Example
{
   static void Main()
   {
      string text = "One car red car blue car";
      // This regex will match the pattern you're looking for
      // Since youre new to regexes :) I'll explain it a little:
      // "--" matches "--" literally, "\s" matches the space in between but only once.
      // "\*" matches the "*" and "\<" and "\>" match "<" and ">" respectively
      // "\d" matches a digit 0-9 and "{3}" indicates that there are three digits 
      string pat = @"--\s\*\<\d{3}\>";

      // Instantiate the regular expression object.
      Regex r = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

      // Match the regular expression pattern against a text string.
      Match m = r.Match(text);
      while (m.Success) 
      {
         // Do something ...
         // Find next match
         m = m.NextMatch();
      }
   }
}
```

This will allow you to make any changes on a per match basis. So every time you match the regex you can do something to your string and then look if there is another match and so on...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Regex.IsMatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y21t6y4(v=vs.110).aspx) using this regular expression `--\\s\\*<\\d+>` for matching strings like `-- *<456>`

```
bool MatchTheNumTag(string str)
{
    Regex reg = new Regex("--\\s\\*<\\d+>");
    return reg.IsMatch(str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following can help you:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string originalString= "\r\radmin@Modem -- *<456> \radmin@Modem -- *<456> ";
        Regex reg = new Regex(@"-- \*<[1-9][0-9]*>");
        bool isMatch = reg.IsMatch(originalString);

        Console.WriteLine(isMatch);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Regexes!

You ave to know that certain characters in regexes are special characters and they need to be escaped, you can find them here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html

Which means that a regex for your pattern would be `\s\-\-\s\*<456>`

`\s` just means whitespace.

Comment: `\s` is not just whitespace. it is equivalent to `[ \t\n]`

Comment: Yeah, but I wanted to keep my answer simple.

Comment: then why add wrong information in it ? in this case you are better off replacing the `\s` with simple spaces.